# Macro to find todays date in a row

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am new to VBA, so please go easy. I am trying to run a macro in a row (specifically Row 4) to find todays date, but everything I have found online is specific to columns. I have tried to create one myself, but it's just not working.  I had some code, but deleted it given the full lack of functionality. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your code that is not working

Comment: Sorry I deleted it. :(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Remember that the macro recorder is your friend and can help you work out many VBA scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start the macro recorder.
- select row 4
- hit Ctrl-F to open the Find dialog
- enter today's date and hit OK
- When the date is highlighted, stop the macro recorder.

Now edit the code. Declare a variable and set it to today's date

```
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = Date
```

Now use the variable myDate instead of the string with today's date in the code.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = Date

'
Rows("4:4").Select
Selection.Find(What:=myDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks very much, worked fine, really appreciate your help. DB